# Datagrid in wpf - no binding required

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid in wpf and a list of structs that I would like to display only some of its properties in the grids.

For example

```
public struct Person
{
   public int age;
   public string name;
   public string hobby;
} 

private List<Person> lst=new List<Person>();
```

I would like to display only name and age in the datagrid. How can I do that in a loop ?

I do this

```
foreach(Person p in lstp)
{ 
   datagrid.Items.Add(p.name);
}
```

But nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Your struct contains no [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), only [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx). Also you end up adding strings directly.

You could add anonymous objects, they use properties:

```
...Add(new { Name = p.name, Age = p.age })
```

(Alternatively you can add properties to your struct and add those directly. If you have more properties than you want to show just create the columns manually, turning [`AutoGenerateColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) off)

Answer (score 0):

```
  datagrid.ItemSource = lst;
```

try this.

sorry, lost the idea.... Just mark the property you don't want by [Browsable(false)] attribute